# Checknullarray with structure

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, structure

```
struct contact list[3];
int checknullarray()
{
    for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        if(strlen(contact[x].name)==0)
        {
        return x;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am having problem with the checknullarray. It say that my type name `(contact[x].name)` is not allowed. What should I do now?

Comment: Well, `strlen()` expects a `[const] char *` argument. What is `contact[x].name`? `contact` doesn't even appear to be a valid variable in the short code you've posted (it is a type of `struct`, though)...

Comment: `contact` looks like a struct. Did you mean `list[x].name`? (though then the 0-9 range of `x` is invalid, because it only has 3 elements)

Comment: after i put list[x].name also got error with it...

Comment: What is contact? HAve a member char*name?

Comment: Give the code for the `contact` struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing contact haves a member like `char name[n];`

```
struct contact list[3];

int checknullarray(void) /* void is a better option when no params */
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) /* 3 or 10 ? I think you want x < 3 */
    {
        /*
        if(strlen(contact[x].name)==0) No need to strlen, you can check if name[0] == 0
        */
        if (list[x].name[0] == '\0')
        {
               return x;
            /*
               break; why break if you return in previous line?
            */
        }
    }
    return x; /* As suggested by qPCR4vir you need an alternative return */
}
```

Comment: and an alternative return?

Comment: We can in c acces x after the cycle?  ..sorry

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun :-)  (the other solution is good)

```
#include "contact.h"
#define N 3
struct contact list[N];

int checknullarray(void)
{
    int x;
    for ( x = 0; x < N && *list[x].name; x++) ;
    return x; 
}
int main(void)
{
   /* initialice list */
   int R;
   R=checknullarray();
   if (R==N) /* No name in list =="" */;
}
```